# Как быстро создать специфический файл в bash или vim?

Tags: bash, vim, scripts

Необходимо создать файл, такой структуры:

```
https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=15
https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=30
https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=45
https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=60
https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=75
....................................................
....................................................
....................................................
https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=1440
```

Думал, создать через VIM скопировать n число раз одну строку, но проблема с редактированием каждой строки.
Пока небольшой опыт работы с VIM и bash.
Просьба помочь в решении данного вопроса.
С Уважением.

Comment: `$ for i in $(seq 15 15 1440); do echo "https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=$i"; done > файл`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое.
Одна строчка сэкономила огромное количество времени.

Answer (score 1):

Проще сделать одностроком на `bash`'е, как *@aleksandrbarakin* в комментариях написал (разбито на строки ради читаемости):

```
for i in $(seq 15 15 1440); do
  echo "https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=$i";
done > файл
```

---

В `vim`'е такое можно сделать с помощью макроса:

- поставить курсор на строку (в командном режиме)

  ```
  https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs=15
  ```
- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> — начать запись макроса в регистр `w`
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> ; <kbd>p</kbd> — скопировать строку и вставить
- <kbd>$</kbd> — перейти в конец строки
- <kbd>15</kbd><kbd>C-A</kbd> — увеличить значение под курсором на `15`
- <kbd>q</kbd> — закончить запись макроса
- <kbd>95</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> — проиграть макрос из регистра `w` `95` раз

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое.
За интересное и оригинальное решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Циклы можно и в Виме писать:

```
:for i in range(15, 1440, 15)
:  $put ='https://www.mysite.com/users/index/cat=1/asnu=1/ofs='..i
:  endfor
```